# Is it possible to get a US visa as a tourist if you lived in the U.S. illegally as a child?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, children

My parents took me as five month old baby to the U.S. illegally. I lived there until I was 15 years old. It's been been 14 years since I left the U.S. What are they possibility of me getting a tourist visa??

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Similar questions have come up a number of times in the past, including *[Can I return to the United States as a tourist after being there illegally for most of my life, as a minor?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111621)*, *[Visiting the US after overstaying as a minor 13 years ago?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55535)*, and *[Applying for a B2 cohabitating visa with previous overstay as a minor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45614)*.